# iOS Use OC Address book on the right side of the sliding retrieval wave effect

Tags: ios

See a url now needs to use the ios to achieve the effect of hope can get help thank you thank you thank you!

https://blog.csdn.net/yuchong1234/article/details/50738485

Comment: Hey Dear MrChen, Can't understand what you want can you add some more details?

Comment: Slide the letters like waves on the left Please look at the url   Thank you very much
https://blog.csdn.net/yuchong1234/article/details/50738485

Comment: OC Address Book is a library can you share link of it's github??

Comment: ok this demo gitHub url  is https://github.com/yuchong123/IndexSideBar

Comment: this github demo is Android demo